# react-create-app prod html from public folder not found for an iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app that needs to embed an html file (along with its own JS and other files) into an iframe on one of the components. I've searched the Facebook react docs on public folder (which says it should work), various other stack overflow questions to no avail.

I added the folder **ixoearth** containing the external files into public folder. [Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCfSp.png)

When I access it in dev mode (localhost:3000), or in prod mode from the network IP it works (eg. 192.168.1.128:63738 ). but as soon as I attempt localhost production mode it doesn't find any of the files in the public folder.

Here's my iframe URL:
[iframe src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfVT1.png)

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When using `create-react-app` you need to use a special `PUBLIC_URL` variable [like is mentioned in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system). This will generate the right path during the build phase so that it works in production.

Comment: This didn't work for me